# What is the Proxy Class

Tags: c#, web-services

Is a web service reference the proxy class itself?  Or is it the classes created inside that you see in object explorer when you look at your web service reference?

example, I created this web service reference

http://www.elbalazo.net/post/TestWebProject%5FObjectExplorer%5FWebReference.jpg

I assume ServiceAuthResponse is one proxy class inside my web service reference?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the WebService reference a proxy class is generated for you.

In your example it looks like LitleWebService will be your service proxy, ServiceAuthResponse sounds more like a data contract that will be used by the service.  If you read about the [Proxy Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternProxy.aspx) it may be of some interest

Normally you proxy will inherit from ClientBase, this is where you can specify the service contract.

```
public class MyProxy : ClientBase<IServiceContract>, IServiceContract
```

Comment: Actually, more than one "proxy class" may be generated. One will be generated as a proxy to the service - others may be generated as proxies to the classes that the service operations accept as input or return as output.